# Search for a function

Tags: calculus, analysis, trigonometry

Good day, I am recently working on a very buffling problem and have come to a function where I'm stuck with trying to express it.

I'm searching for a trigonometric function that can express or approach that specific function at least in the area [-1; 1].
I've tried to create a taylor series but failed and the current functional equation of that function is unuseful to me.

If anybody has seen a function looking like this or knows an equation anything close to this - it would help.

Thank you! :)

The exact functional equation of this function is:
$sin(\pi*x)*(-\frac{\Psi(1+x)+\Psi(1-x)}{2}-\gamma)$

Additional information: Plotting this function results in undefined values at all integers. at x=0 it approaches 0, otherwise: positive even integers and negative odd integers $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and positive odds and negative evens are $-\frac{\pi}{2}$

The second known value is this one: $f(\frac{1}{2})=2*\ln(2)-1$

It is an expression of the digamma function

[image: Full function]

The function in more detail in the area of $[0;1]$

[image: Closeup]

Comment: If you tell us the problem, it may help us come up with what the function is.

Comment: It looks similar to $\sqrt{|x|}\sin(x)$.  Looking only at the peaks gave me the thought of the $\sqrt{x}$ part, the fact that it remained real forced the absolute value inside of the squareroot, and the sine part of course for the waviness.  Try shifting and scaling that around to fit what you want, but beyond that its difficult to really guess.

Comment: I have added the functional equation

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

$$f(x) = \sin(x^3)$$

[image]

Since you need it in the range $[-1, 1]$ it seems quite good to me. Let us know!

Comment: Really close at the region of 0 and $\pm \frac{1}{2}$ but unfortunetly off at the rest

Comment: An even closer approximation is $((x + 0.7)^2 (x - 0.7)^2 + 0.96)sin(\pi x^3)$

Comment: I'll think about something else then! Thank you! :D

Comment: No, thank you! :) Maybe the functional equation helps, but this is a very strange problem

Comment: It's a curious one indeed. It's never easy to guess a function simply by its plot. But it's challenging :D

Comment: True, and it's more frustrating the more you know, the amplitude of this function seams to rise to infinity but slower than logartithmic and the extremas of the function head to 1/2, but approach that very very slow. (A maxima is for example apprx. at 2515.44 and has the value of ~8.55, the maximum I can go)

Answer (score 0):

*This is probably too long for a comment.*

First, let us look at the Taylor expansion (built around $x=0$) of the functional equation
$$f(x)=-\sin(\pi x)\,\left(\frac{\Psi(1+x)+\Psi(1-x)}{2}+\gamma\right)$$ It is given by 
$$-\frac{1}{2} x^3 (\pi  \psi ^{(2)}(1))+x^5 \left(\frac{\pi ^3 \psi
   ^{(2)}(1)}{12}-\frac{\pi  \psi ^{(4)}(1)}{24}\right)+O\left(x^7\right)$$ making the idea of a model $$g(x)=\frac \pi 2 \sin\left(\frac \pi 2 x^a\right)$$ (with $a\approx 3$) interesting (at least, the end points are satisfied).

Considering now $$\Phi(a)=\int_0^1\left(f(x)-g(x)\right)^2\,dx$$ and minimizing leads to an optimum for $a=2.75$ which is not too bad but not fantastic $(\Phi(2.75)=0.000910148)$.

Comment: Thank you sir, off to a good start of tweaking that one until it fits the function pretty well :)